# How to detect edeges android opencv

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I'm using android opencv 2.4.8 for image processing. I tired to search everywhere. but not get valid answer. my image name is pic1.jpg , It's in drawable folder. I create Imageview to show edges. Image View object name is img. I need to show edeges in Imageview. can any one know answer?

Answer (score 5):

So you got your image as bmp, just convert it opencv Mat,

```
Bitmap bmp; //input image
Mat srcMat = new Mat ( bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
Bitmap myBitmap32 = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32, srcMat);
```

Now perform canny edge detection on converted Mat, before that convert to gray,

```
Mat gray = new Mat(srcMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY,4);
```

Perform canny and convert to 4 channel

```
Mat edge = new Mat();
Mat dst = new Mat();
Imgproc.Canny(gray, edge, 80, 90);
Imgproc.cvtColor(edge, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA,4);
```

Finally convert to bitmap

```
Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dst.cols(), dst.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);           
Utils.matToBitmap(dst, resultBitmap);
```

Now display the image in layout.

Also you can refer **image-manipulations** on opencv-android-sdk folder.

*Note: The above code is not tested.!*

Comment: This is a seriously thorough answer for this question.